# How do I retrieve data from multiple nodes in Firebase? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the questions from the questions node from each user as shown in the diagram below. I can't figure out a way to reach the nodes. How do I retrieve the data from each of the question nodes of the separate users?? someone please help.
[image]

Comment: Hi, willy. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What I have done is that I can access the question from one user, but I do not know how to access the questions from multiple users at the same time.

Comment: questionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users") -- from this part I dont know what node I should put next,

Answer (score 1):

To access the questions of all users you'd do something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot questionsSnapshot = userSnapshot.child("questions");
            Log.i(TAG, "User "+userSnapshot.getKey()+" has "+questionsSnapshot.numChildren()+" questions");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

I highly recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) as you are nesting data of different types here, which goes against the recommendation to [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).